# Computing minimal polynomials and finding linear combinations

Tags: field-theory, minimal-polynomials

I'm dealing with the following polynomial $f(x)= x^3 + 2x +3 $. This is irreducible(over $\mathbb{Q}$ by Eisenstein's criterion.Let $\alpha$ denote one of its roots. Two questions regarding this polynomial:

$(a)$ Express the elements $\alpha^{-1}$ and $\beta = \alpha^6 + 3\alpha^4 +2\alpha^3 +6\alpha$ as linear combinations of $1, \alpha, \alpha^2$.

$(b)$ Determine the minimal polynomial of $\beta$ over $\mathbb{Q}$

My work:

For $(a)$, $\beta = \alpha^3(\alpha^3 + 3\alpha +2 +\frac{6}{\alpha^2})= \alpha^3(0+ \frac{6}{\alpha^2})= 6\alpha $, so it can be expressed as a linear combination of $\alpha$.  But what about $\alpha^{-1}$? I do not see how it can be written as a linear combination of $1, \alpha, \alpha^2$.

For $(b)$ I noted that since $\alpha^3 + 3\alpha +2 = 0$ and $\beta = 6\alpha$, hence a polynomial where $\beta$ would be the solution is $\beta^3 + 72\beta +864$. In $\mathbb{Z}_{5},$ this reduces to $\beta^3 +2\beta +4$. But, this polynomial has no solutions in $\mathbb{Z}_{5}$, hence this polynomial is also irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$. So, it is a minimal polynomial. Is my work correct?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you mean $f(x)=x^3+3x+2$?

Comment: To write $\alpha^{-1}$ in this way, solve the equation $\alpha(a+b\alpha+c\alpha^2)=1$ where $a,b,c\in\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: @PeterHuxford I set $c \alpha^3 + b \alpha^2 + \alpha a -1 = \alpha^3 + 2\alpha +2$, which gives $c=1, b= 0, a = \frac{3}{\alpha}$. But, $\alpha$ is not rational. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Happy to write an answer, but first can you clarify whether $f(x) = x^3 + 3x + 2$ or $f(x) = x^3 + 2x + 3$? Your post states the latter, but some of your calculations suggest the former is what you're using.